# Activity or fragment with DrawerLayout for Top Navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an app with a DrawerLayout. 
Let's say I have 5 Entries for top navigation.

What is the best way to structure my application?

Should I use 5 activities
or 5 fragments inside the MainActivity which I change when an item gets selected.

As I currently see it 5 fragments would be OK, but maybe I missed some points:

- performance implications
- maintaining code could get messy
- any features I cannot use without having separate activities
- UX downsides

Comment: I normally have 1 activity, then fragments for the respective parts of the app;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main reason to use Fragments are for the backstack and lifecycle features. Otherwise, custom views are more light weight and simpler to implement.**

I'd say Fragments are useful in two scenarios: if you split up views on some devices/orientations and show them in two activities and show all the content in one on other devices. That would be a use case if you go on a tablet or maybe even in landscape mode on a phone: e.g. you show the list of items and the details on one screen. on a phone or in portrait mode you just show one part.

Another use case are reusable views. So if you have some views that are visible on different activities and also perform some actions you could put this behaviour int

Comment: What do you mean by custom views?
E.g. I have a layout which consists of 2 Text-, 2 ImageViews and some padding.
I can reuse this with <include>. 
But I cannot set the ImageSource or the Text to display trough xml. 
Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Check out the link tham am add follows it gives you a clear picture http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use fragment. DrawerLayout normally use fragment instead of Activity because with fragment you can find out which layout is active which cannot be done in Activity

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) you should use fragments when you are about to reuse that part of the UI or when you want to create a multi-pane view for large screens.

> Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11), primarily to support more dynamic and flexible UI designs on large screens, such as tablets.

So the choice should be clear once you map your use case.

Comment: You are right about the initial intention from Google.
But I can (mis)use fragments for lightweight activities even if don't have a multi-pane layout because the concept is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

I would say fragment is the answer.Supports toggle facility just by a simple implementation in each new fragments and is more flexible to perform various activities